# ScrollView doesn't work properly in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uiscrollview

I would display a view in my iOS app, but when I try to use ScrollView, even if I put stack views, it doesn't work.

Here is a screenshot of my storyboard:

[image: storyboard]

I do tests with a long description I put in my code, but the scroll view doesn't work properly. Here are the constraints of my View Controller:

[image: contraints]

Where the problem could come from?

---

**EDIT:**

After deleting the `View.centerY = centerY`, I get this error:

> Scroll View: Need constraints for: Y position or height

Here is my new constraints:

[image: new]

Comment: Try removing the constraint View.centerY = centerY. and set the bottom constraint of the collection view to the scroll view's bottom. This could be due to the height of the screen and you are also setting the y constraint in the same case.

Comment: Thanks, I deleted the constraint but I don't know how to fix the new error. I don't know which contraint to add to fix the "Need constraint for: Y position or height". I edited my first post with screenshot and more details.

Comment: I hope your problem is solved already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Constraint `View.centerY = centerY` between the content view and the `scrollView` will prevent scrolling. Drop that constraint.

Comment: I edited my question with your suggest, but I still have an error about the Y position which is missing. Do you know which constraint I should add to fix it?

Comment: @cusmar well, height has to be determined by the content, so just make sure that the stuff that you put inside of the content view has properly setup constraints for all the sides, and it should work

Comment: It works fine! Thanks! But a last thing, when I scroll to the top, I have the white space of the status bar which appears. Do you know where it comes from?

Comment: @cusmar I'm not sure if I understand what you are asking about, but my best guess would be that it's a result of using safe area guide.. I'm not sure how storyboard's work, but make sure you dont use safe area (from your screenshot I assume you don't in constraining the scrollView top), and try to look around for marrgins and stuff.. e.g., when you click on scrollView, in `Size Inspector` tab on the right, uncheck `Safe Area Relative Margins` in section `Layout Margins`

Comment: @cusmar did that help?

Comment: No it doesn't, but I will find by myself. It was not the question here. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164548/discussion-between-cusmar-and-milan-nosa).